# probability for two people to arrange something in the same order

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

What is the probability that two people independently arrange for instance a sequence of the $10$ elements: $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$, in the same order?

I'm not sure how I should go about this problem, is it just $\frac{1}{10!}$?

Comment: If all $10!$ orderings are equally likely for at least one of the two people, then your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $10!$ possible arrangements for the first person, and any of these will do. For the second person to match the first person's order, they must arrange the numbers in the exact order that person 1 did, meaning there is a probability of $1$ in $10!$ that they are in the same order.

So yes, you are correct.

Mathematically, the most intuitive way to think of it (imo) is the following:

$$\frac{1}{(10!)^2}\cdot10!$$

Where each person chooses $1$ in $10!$ possible arrangements, but there are also $10!$ possible arrangements both can choose.